# Message on Reaction discord.js

Tags: discord.js, bots

I been trying to make my bot reply to users when they react to the bots emoji but no luck I hope someone can help me here, I'm just a beginner with discord.js.

here's my code I just need help with the part where the bot sends a message back once the user reacts to it.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) 
    {
        if(message.embeds)
        {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Next step');
            if(embedMsg)
            {
                message.react('708923041928839169')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('708923028846805073'))
                .catch(err => console.error);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'done'){
      
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('Next step')
        embed.setColor(colors.blue);
        embed.setDescription('Please react to Agree or Disagree');
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }

  });

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `ReactionCollector` to do this. The documentation for this can be found easily on the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org), and I would recommend you look there when unsure of how to do something before asking a question on StackOverflow.

Here's an example using your code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'done'){
  
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('Next step')
        embed.setColor(colors.blue);
        embed.setDescription('Please react to Agree or Disagree');
        message.channel.send(embed).then(embedMsg => {
            embedMsg.react('708923041928839169')
            .then(reaction => embedMsg.react('708923028846805073'))
            .catch(err => console.error);

            const filter = (r, u) => r.emoji.id == '708923041928839169' || r.emoji.id == "708923028846805073";
            const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000});
            collector.on('collect', (r, u) => {
               //Put your response to reactions here
               message.channel.send("Reply with something to " + u.tag + " because they reacted with " + r.emoji.name);
            });
        })
    }

});

bot.login(token);
```

I also moved your code in which you add the reactions to the Embed, because the way you were doing it was an unnecessary extra step.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector

Comment: hey @Cannicide your example works but the response to the reaction is not working can you check it out??

Comment: Apologies @SinKnight, I accidentally caused the `ReactionCollector` to only check for the reaction with ID "708923041928839169" and not the one with ID "708923028846805073" due to a typo in my answer. I'm assuming that's what the problem was, and I've updated my answer with the correction. Also note that this example has a time limit of 60 seconds set, so responses will no longer occur a minute after the embed is sent (adjust `time` in the collector's options to change that).